# JSTL breaks on GoogleAppEngine's development server, but works on remote server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jstl

As the title says, my JSTL tags don't work on my development server, but do work on Google's actual server.

I simplified the code to the bare bone to make sure there wasn't anything wrong with the code, so here's what I've got.

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${2+2==4}">sum works</c:when>
        <c:otherwise>sum doesn't work</c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</body>
```

My configuration is as follows (which I think is correct and which works on Google's server): 
 I'm using

- Eclipse IDE
- Servlet 2.5
- No jstl jar added to WEB-INF\lib
- No tld added anywhere
- No taglib reference

on web.xml

However, I have also tried a number of combinations of the following and none of them worked:

- jstl-1.2.jar added to the build path
- c.tld added to WEB-INF
- taglib reference added to web.xml

Error is below:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /index.html. Reason: 

    javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:927)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:298)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:87)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:87)
         ...
```

Strangely, though, `<c:out value="${blah}"/>` works both on the development and remote servers. other core tags don't work. If I try to add fmt tags, they don't work as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that google searches were returning no useful information already indicated that this problem was unique to my configuration.

Alas, I finally managed to figure out what was wrong and I'm just posting the solution in case someone comes across this problem, which dreaded me for days.

Turned out I had added Tomcat's servlet-api.jar and jstl jar into Eclipse's default JRE library to avoid having to add them each time into WEB-INF\lib (i.e. Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Edit > Add External Jar).

Once I started developing in GAE, this configuration started causing a conflict with AppEngine's own servlet-api.jar and jstl jars.

The answer was simply to remove the Tomcat jars from the JRE library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop JSTL JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` or at least in the `/lib` folder of the servletcontainer which you're using on local development.

You should **not** extract the JAR and clutter the webapp with loose TLD files and also not reference it anywhere in `web.xml`. Undo everything if you have done it. You should also not have the need to manually add it to Eclipse build path. Just dropping in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder ought to be enough.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, but still no cookie. This is what I did now: 1) cleaned everything: removed jstl from WEB-INF\lib, removed all references to the taglib from web.xml (i.e. `<jsp-config><taglib>`), made sure that there are no loose tlds, 2) readded jstl-1.2.jar to WEB-INF\lib and did not add it to the build path, 3) added the following to the jsp `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`. I also think it should work, but id doesn't!

Comment: The strange thing is that, just like before, it still works on Google's remote server. The problem is making it work on my local development server. Also, the tag `<c:out>` **does** work, so I'm thinking maybe there might be something on GAE's local configuration that is preventing other tags from working...?

Comment: It would have worked on all normal servletcontainers like Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, etc. I must however admit that I've never worked with GAE and that I've seen several strange issues like that are been posted here before. So, I think that it needs to be altered/fixed at local GAE level.

Comment: Thanks nonetheless. I had it working on Tomcat, so I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: I googled a bit and it seems that you need to declare `web.xml` as Servlet 2.4: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/06/18/jstl-issue-with-gaej-and-spring/ Give it a try.

Comment: For a moment there I thought you would take me out of my mysery, but still nothing. I remember seeing that article and trying it a couple days ago, but it was early in my struggles and I forgot about it afterwards. Thanks for the spending the time. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Try with [JSTL 1.1](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/jakarta-taglibs-standard-current.zip) (jstl.jar and standard.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` instead while still having Servlet 2.4 in `web.xml`.

Comment: and... doesn't work. I initially wanted it to work on my dev server to avoid spending the time to deploy the app to Google's server (each upload could take over a minute). But now, waiting for it to upload each time would probably take less time than figuring out a solution.....